# How to normalize/flatten a set attribute to an intersection table using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, database-normalization

I was given the task to improve an old database. I can work with phpMyAdmin that connects to a MariaDB.

There's a table Region with a column called Super. The Super attribute stores the m:m-relationship to a table called Subcontinents. Here's the catch: instead of using an intersection table, Super is of the type Set/Enum and contains *all* subcontinents associated with a given region. The allowed values are hardcoded in the table definition and are *not* linked with a foreign key.

**Regions Definition**

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int(11) |
| Name | text |
| Super | set('1', '2', ...) `= Ids of Subcontinents table` |

**Regions Example**

| Id | Name | Super |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Atlas | 17 |
| 456 | Europe | 8,9,10,11 |

**Subcontinents Definition**

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | int(11) |
| Subcontinent | text |

**Subcontinents Example**

| Id | Subcontinent |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | Northern Europe |
| 9 | Eastern Europe |
| 10 | Southern Europe |
| 11 | Western Europe |
| 17 | Eastern Africa |

What I want to do now, is to create an intersection table between the two tables. I could not find out, how I can flatten the records with multiple Super values. The desired output would be something similar to this:

| RegionId | SubcontinentId |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 17 |
| 456 | 8 |
| 456 | 9 |
| 456 | 10 |
| 456 | 11 |

I tried to query the Super attribute like `SELECT id, super, (SELECT * FROM super) as target FROM Region` but apparently that's invlalid syntax. I also tried to map the set value to an integer, but I didn't now how to proceed from there either. Searching the internet brought up a lot of material about normalizing databases, sadly none of it contained an example with a set.

PS: I know how to create tables, move data between them and add constraints.

Comment: *I know how to create tables, move data between them and add constraints.* It's a time to read about data quering and JOINs.

Comment: I'm familiar with that too, thank you. I was not familiar with the SET data type though. Digging a bit deeper helped me to find FIND_IN_SET, which is what I searched for.

Comment: a) FIND_IN_SET() is string function which is slow and cannot use indices. b) If you can use FIND_IN_SET() then your data have no SET datatype, it is string-type data which stores CSV values pack. c) Your data is not safe for FIND_IN_SET() - ensure: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94fb725c8efb97ae0b1f337d28a87a62 The space after a comma is a part of value.

Comment: *If I get that correctly, then it still fits?* In this case your info in the question is not correct.

Comment: phpMyAdmin displays the columns type as `SET`. I don't know how it's stored. Regarding a), I only need it to normalize the db, so if the performance is bad that's fine. b) A quick test showed that it seems to work the way I need. c) Thank you very much for pointing this out, I wasn't aware. Luckily I don't think there are values with spaces in the table though. I edit my question to remove the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's a function [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/find_in_set/) which helps with this problem. The syntax is:

```sql
FIND_IN_SET(pattern, strlist)
```

One can use it as a condition in a join:

```sql
SELECT r.id, r.super, s.id
  FROM Region as r
  JOIN Subcontinents as s
    ON FIND_IN_SET(s.id, r.super)
```

Which results in:

| r.id | r.super | s.id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 8,9,10,11 | 8 |
| 456 | 8,9,10,11 | 9 |
| 456 | 8,9,10,11 | 10 |
| 456 | 8,9,10,11 | 11 |

Please be aware of the pitfalls @Akina pointed out in the comments:

- There're no sets, they're in fact CSV value packs.
- `FIND_IN_SET` is a string function.
- Spaces matter. `8,9,10` is not the same as `8, 9, 10`. In the latter, `8` would be found by `FIND_IN_SET`, but `9` (missing the leading space) won't.
- Performance is bad.